# Comparing two or more linear regression lines

Tags: regression, anova, t-test, linear

During chemical analysis in our labs the analysts found a variation between the measured standardization lines. This variation led to doubts concerning the quality of the measured standardization lines. These lines were fit to data using ordinary linear regression.

How can I statistically prove that there is or isn't a difference between the linear regression lines?

Comment: Can you say more about what the "X" and "Y" axes are for these lines?

Comment: The x-as contains the known concentrations of a drug (cefazoline) and the y-ax contains the signal measured by our HPLC. with these data we made straight lines also know as standardization lines. We use these lines to calculate the unknown drug concentrations in tablets or drinks containing the drug.

Comment: What are the two slopes you're trying to compare? Fill in the blanks: _ / _ versus _ / _

Comment: There should be a zero signal when the drug is not present, so if some of the regressions do predict this characteristic and some do not then that should be useful information.

Comment: delta Y/ delta X (of line 1) vs delta y/delta x o(f line 2)

Comment: @Samelo It's still not clear what you are doing. Are the observations here samples of the same drug at different concentrations, or are you measuring abundance of a molecule as the drug goes through some phase change? It might be useful to cite units.

Comment: Ok, what is line 1 and what is line 2?

Comment: We made different samples with known drug concentration, so sample 1 contains 10 ug/ml, sample 2 contains 20 ug/ml, sample 3 contains 40 ug/ml, sample 4 contains 80 ug/ml and smaple 5 contains: 160 ug/ml. When we inject those samples in our machine (HPLC) we measure signals. So each sample has its own signal. The measured signal is our Y-value. we have done this proces twice (so 2 stets of samples) under the same conditions. And it resulted in slighlty different lines. Now i want to analyse if the differnce between the two lines is statistically significant. I hope this clears it up

Comment: Line 1 is the first set of samples. Line 2 is the second set of samples. Normally the lines would be the same as the used samples in both line have the same drug concentration.

Comment: @Samelo, Do you get coefficients associated with the Xs? Do you include an intercept term in your models?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the null hypothesis is that there is no fundamental difference between the two fitted lines of the sample sets $D_1$ and $D_2$.

Suppose you remove a point $(x_1, y_1)$ from $D_1$, forming $D'_1$, and a point $(x_2, y_2)$ from $D_2$, forming $D'_2$. Fit a line $l_1$ to $D'_1$, and a line $l_2$ to $D'_2$. Under the null hypothesis, it is random whether

$$
  \left(l_1(x_1) - y_1\right)^2 + \left(l_2(x_2) - y_2\right)^2
  < 
\left(l_1(x_2) - y_2\right)^2 + \left(l_2(x_1) - y_1\right)^2
,
$$ 
that is, whether the points fit better their original datasets rather than if they are exchanged.

Repeat this now for many (possibly all) pairs of points from $D_1$ and $D_2$. Under the null hypothesis, if you perform this $n$ times, the results should be $\sim B\left( \frac{1}{2}, n \right)$. Essentially, this reduces the problem to [determining whether a coin is fair](http://www.csus.edu/indiv/j/jgehrman/courses/stat50/hypthesistests/9hyptest.htm). The "coin toss" here is just whether samples better match the lines from their own original groups or not.